# Rhino Mocks: reset recorded call

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have a method CreateGraph(DateTime) that takes a long time to execute.

I don't want to call it if not needed, hence, it the input parameter is not changed, I do not want to call CreateGraph, but return the already created Graph:

```
IGraphFactor GraphFactory {get; set;}
DateTime LastCreatedGraphDate {get; private set;}
IGraph LastCreatedGraph {get; private set;}

IGraph FetchGraph(DateTime graphDate)
{
    if (graphDate != LastCreatedGraph && this.LastCreatedGraph != null)
    {
        this.LastCreatedGraph = this.GraphFactory.CreateGraph(graphDate);
    }
    return this.LastCreatedGraph;
}
```

Simple comme bonjour.

Now I want to test it using Rhino Mocks. First FetchGraph for some testDate, then Fetch it again and assert that the re-fetch does not call GraphFactory.CreateGraph again:

Using the Arrange - Act - Assert pattern:

```
// Arrange:
IGraph mockedGraph = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IGraph>();
IGraphBuilder mockedGraphBuilder MockRepository.GenerateMock<IGraphBuilder>();

// mockedGraphBuilder.CreateGraph returns a mockedGraph:
mockedGraphBuilder.Stub( (graphBuilder) => graphBuilder.CreateGraph(Arg<DateTime>.Is.Anything))
                  .Return(mockedGraph);

DateTime testDate = ...
var myTestObject = ...
myTestObject.FetchGraph(testDate);
// This will probably have called GraphBuilder.CreateGraph.
// I Need to reset this recording before Act
// how to reset?

// now that I know that LastCreatedGraphDate equals testDate I can act:
// Act: fetch the graph for the same date again:
myTestObject.FetchGraph(testDate);

// Assert: should not be called
mockedGraphBuilder.AssertNotCalled((graphBuilder) => graphBuilder.CreateGraph(Arg<DateTime>.Is.Anything))
```

This fails, because the first call was recorded.

To reset I tried: mockedGraphBuilder.Replay, and mockedGraphBuilder.BackToRecord but that does not work. How to reset the recording, so that it is as if the method is not called yet?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the test to see whether your if condition fails on the second FetchGraph() call? What's the value of LastCreatedGraph on the second call?

Comment: Yes, I've debugged it. I'm sure the CreateGraph is not called twice. So alternatively I could assert that it was called once, but I don't want in this test the dependancy that setting it for the first time will only call it once. I want to reset the recorded call as if it was not called yet

Comment: Can't you create another test where you can first set the LastCreatedGraph to some datetime and then pass the same datetime to FetchGraph()? It virtually means that you are mimicking the fact that the first FetchGraph() call is made (but not made in test) and then you are making the second call?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse your approach is over-complicating things. Call the subject member twice and assert that the dependency is called once. Also in the shown example you have `IGraphFactory` in the SUT and `IGraphBuilder` in the test. Which is is? The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.